# SQL tedious add array as parameter

Tags: sql, node.js, tedious

I'm running this SQL query with `tedious.js` using parameters:

```
var query = "select * from table_name where id in (@ids)";
request = new sql.Request(query, function(err, rowCount) {
  if (err) {
  }
});

request.on('row', function(columns) {
});

var id = [1, 2, 3];
request.addParameters('ids', TYPES.Int, id);

connection.execSql(request);
```

because I am looking for items that matches the ID provided with `where ... in ...` clause, I need to pass in an array. However, there is no TYPES.Array. How do I this properly?

Comment: did you ever manage to work this out? I am having the same issue. Trying to have just a varchar type that has a joined array as it's value. no luck. says it succeeds but it does not

Answer (score 0):

for this query, i think you'll just have to manually build the entire sql string. the `TYPES` enum values are for the datatypes in the database, not in your  JavaScript code.

Comment: I have no problem building the entire SQL string. However, I'm afraid of SQL Injection attack, that's why I try to stick to parameters if I can.

Answer (score 0):

//you can like  this:

```
var userIds = result.map(function (el) {
                return el.UserId;
            }).join(',');

var params = [{
name: 'userIds',
type: TYPES.VarChar,
value: userIds,
options: null}];

var querySql = ['SELECT  COUNT([MomentId]) FROM [T_Moment]',
        'WHERE [RecordStatus] = ', sysConst.recordStatus.activation, " AND CHARINDEX(','+RTRIM([UserId])+',' , ','+ @userIds +',')>0 "].join(' ');

    dbHelper.count(querySql, params, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            callback('error--');
        } else {
            callback(null, result);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the in clause parameters for query dynamically.

```
// create connection 
let ids = [1, 2, 3];
let inClauseParamters = createInClauseParameters();
let query = `select * from table_name where id in (${inClauseParamters})`;
let request = new Request(query, (err, rowCount) => {
    if (err) { /* handle error */ }
});

request.on('row', (columns) => { /* get row */});
request = addRequestParameters(ids, request);
connection.execSql(request);


function createInClauseParameters(values) {
    return values.map((val, index) => `@Value${index}`).join(',');
}

function addRequestParameters(values, request) {
    values.forEach((val, index) => {
        request.addParameter(`Value${index}`, TYPES.VarChar, val);
    });
    return request;
}
```